# Referencing data in a geoJSON file

Tags: javascript

JS novice.  This statement appears not to be working:

```
if (kcdfp_parcel[i].InActive == 0)
```

The data is a geoJSON file with the variable "kcdfp_parcel".

This is a little of the file:

kcdfp_parcel = [{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

```
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "MAJOR": "000440", "MINOR": "0018", "PIN": "0004400018", "FarmID": 3101.000000, "LastName": "Codiga", "Acres": 62.940000, "Cooperativ": null, "InActive": 0, "ParcelNumb": "0004400018", "Shape_Leng": 0.024319, "Shape_Area": 0.000030 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.254601971999989,
```

Am I referencing the LastName field properly (e.g. do I need to use kcdfp_parcel.features.InActive)?

Or, is my IF statement wrong?

Comment: is "features" apart of the kcdfp_parcel var?  also, you should run your json through a formatter of some sort to make it a bit more readable in your question.

Comment: if "features" IS apart of kcdfp_parcel, I think you can reference it this way: `kcdfp_parcel[0].features[0].properties.InActive`

kcdfp_parcel and features both are arrays in your post hence the need for index references

Comment: Sorry for not simplifying format.  Still new and getting used to stackoverflow courtesies.  I've simplified the geoJSON considerably including realizing kcdfp_parcel doesn't need to be an array.  Kcdfp_parcel is a variable with 3 JSON keyword entries that occur only once in the file:

Comment: kcdfp_parcel = {

"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "…" } },
"features": [

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "InActive": 0, "ParcelNumb": "0004400018" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.254601971999989, 47.364317413000038 ], [ -122.254231611999955, 47.364320569000029 ] ] ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "InActive": 0, "ParcelNumb": "0006400009" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -122.059132819999945, 47.197189012000081 ], [ -122.059119953999982, 47.197182407000071 ] ] ] } },

Comment: Ignore the punctuation.  Didn't try to get it right as I extracted sample data.  Also, sorry I couldn't figure out how to highlight the entry as CODE.  So how do I reference the "InActive" field in the "features" array in JS?

Comment: Is it kcdfp_parcel.features[i].InActive?

Comment: Looks like kcdfp_parcel.features[i].properties.InActive should do it for you with the new JSON you posted as a comment

Comment: Sorry Zack.  Still having issues (nothing is displayed on the map.  I've put the JS code in JSFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/j7dcbsa7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to reference "InActive" via `kcdfp_parcel.features[some_index].properties.InActive` like in the example below.  Output on the browser console via `console.log` looks like this:

> Features index 0 has property InActive of 0 and ParcelNumb of
>   0004400018
>   Features index 1 has property InActive of 0 and ParcelNumb
>   of 0006400009

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
        <h1>Check your browser console...</h1>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var kcdfp_parcel = { 
            "type": "FeatureCollection", 
            "crs": { 
                "type": "name", 
                "properties": { 
                   "name": "…" 
                } 
            }, 
            "features": [ 
                { 
                    "type": "Feature", 
                    "properties": { 
                        "InActive": 0, 
                        "ParcelNumb": "0004400018" 
                    }, 
                    "geometry": { 
                        "type": "Polygon", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.254601971999989, 47.364317413000038 ], [ -122.254231611999955, 47.364320569000029 ] ] ] 
                    } 
                }, 
                { 
                    "type": "Feature", 
                    "properties": { 
                        "InActive": 0, 
                        "ParcelNumb": "0006400009" 
                    }, 
                    "geometry": { 
                       "type": "MultiPolygon", 
                       "coordinates": [ [ [ -122.059132819999945, 47.197189012000081 ], [ -122.059119953999982, 47.197182407000071 ] ] ] 
                    } 
                } 
            ]
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < kcdfp_parcel.features.length; i++) {
            console.log("Features index " + i + " has property InActive of " + kcdfp_parcel.features[i].properties.InActive + 
                        " and ParcelNumb of " + kcdfp_parcel.features[i].properties.ParcelNumb);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Zach for both the analysis and the simple example.  Still not able to get the map layer to show, but I now understand how to reference the JSON entry.  Suspect it may be the way I'm calling Leaflet.